# Convex hulls have longer boundaries

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $C$ be a rectifiable simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $D$ be the boundary of the convex hull of the region bounded by $C$.  What is the most efficient way to prove that $D$ is rectifiable and that the length of $D$ is at most the length of $C$?

Comment: Title should be "Convex hulls have *shorter* boundaries", right?

Answer (score 4):

The magic words are: [The Crofton Formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula)